# topbar fixa na janela do browser

Tags: novo-recurso

Geralmente, ao navegar pelos sites do Stack Exchange, eu mal olho nessa barra superior e acaba por passar despercebido varias notificações que poderiam ter sido vistas na hora que foram lançadas, a minha sugestão é: fixar essa topbar na janela do navegador, creio que não vai atrapalhar a visualização do resto do site.

Comment: Seria o mesmo que foi pedido aqui? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1591/menu-superior-fixo-no-topo-da-tela

Comment: Não exatamente, aqui seria apenas a barra preta.

Comment: Alguma resposta?

Comment: Pedidos de novo recurso ficam na mão da Stack Exchange, que decide o que vai ou não implementar. Se quiser aumentar as chances de ter seu pedido atendido, torne esta pergunta mais atraente, argumentando de maneira mais consistente sobre as vantagens do que você propõe. Tenha em mente que pedidos desse tipo afetariam todos os sites da rede, então são muito mais delicados. Eu acho que as chances de atenderem isso são nulas, ainda mais considerando que o mesmo já foi pedido e recusado no MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210241/what-about-a-fixed-top-bar-for-better-ease-of-access